# When I use DropDownListFor, I can display the selected item but the Id is not true

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I have two different tables one of them is Products, another one is Categories.
Categories table has two column as Id and Name,
Products table has four column as Name, TWS, OWS, and CategoryId. I display CategoryName instead of CategoryId on the Title Page.

I have Create page to add Products. In this page I want to use a dropdownlist to add CategoryId and again I want to show the CategoryName instead of Category Id.

First of all, I worked on the Create() method.

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectListItem = _context.Categories.
                                               Select(i=> new SelectListItem()
                                               {
                                                   Text = i.Name,
                                                   Value = i.Id.ToString()
                                               }).ToList();
        ViewBag.selectedListItem = selectListItem;
        return View();
    }
```

After that I worked on the Create.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category.Id,(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.selectedListItem, new {@class="form-group"})
                <span asp-validation-for="CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

**m => m.Category.Id** In here category is getting from Project.Models.Products.

Finally, I worked on Create(Products products) method.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Products products)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Products existingTitle = await _context.Products.SingleOrDefaultAsync(
               x => x.Name == products.Name);

            if (existingTitle != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "This data already exists.");
                return View(products);
            }
            else
            {
                var ctg = _context.Categories.Where(m =>m.Id==products.Category.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                products.Category= ctg;
                products.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                _context.Add(products);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            
        }
        return View(products);
    }
```

I get this error when I try to add a new product.
*An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
lambda_method(Closure )*

I made a change in code like that:

```
var ctg = _context.Categories.Where(m =>m.Id==products.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault();
```

This time, the Product can be added but the categoryid of this product is not equal the selected category. The category Id is always 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.

So, how can I fix this issue.

Comment: is product.category.id is having a value in it and where are you setting a value in product.category.id

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the last code blok. I just fix. 
var ctg = _context.Categories.Where(m =>m.Id==products.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault(); with this, code is working with default guid ıd.  I set the value of product.CategoryID in Index() of products

Comment: ' var products = _context.products
                                .Select(m => new Products()
                                {
                                    Name = m.Name,
                                    OWS = m.OWS,
                                    TWS = m.TWS
                                    CategoryName = m.Category.Name,
                                    CategoryId=m.Category.Id
                                    
                                }); '

Comment: Hi @simoncare,any update about this case?

Comment: Hi, @Yinqiu I fix the issue. There are lots of  Category and Id combinations in the project like CategoryID Category.Id Categories.Id. I analyze which one is which one, after that I apply your solution, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite clear about the relationship between your models, but you can see a simple working example of mine below.

Model:

```
public class Category
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TWS { get; set; }
    public string OWS { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
 public IActionResult Create()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectListItem = _context.Categories.
                                               Select(i => new SelectListItem()
                                               {
                                                   Text = i.Name,
                                                   Value = i.Id.ToString()
                                               }).ToList();
        ViewBag.selectedListItem = selectListItem;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Product products)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Product existingTitle = await _context.Products.SingleOrDefaultAsync(
               x => x.Name == products.Name);

            if (existingTitle != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "This data already exists.");
                List<SelectListItem> selectListItem = _context.Categories.
                                             Select(i => new SelectListItem()
                                             {
                                                 Text = i.Name,
                                                 Value = i.Id.ToString()
                                             }).ToList();
                ViewBag.selectedListItem = selectListItem;
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                var ctg = _context.Categories.Where(m => m.Id == products.Category.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                products.Category = ctg;
                products.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                _context.Add(products);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@model Product
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessage("Error")</span>
        <input asp-for="Name" />
        @*//...*@
        <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category.Id, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.selectedListItem, new { @class = "form-group" })
        <span asp-validation-for="Category.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

By the way,if you want use code:

```
var ctg = _context.Categories.Where(m =>m.Id==products.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault();
```

You need to change the dropdown to:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId,(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.selectedListItem, new {@class="form-group"})
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: If this does not meet your needs, you can share your model.

Comment: public class Products
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string OWS { get; set; }
        public string TWS { get; set; }
        public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Guid CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public virtual Categories Category { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Does my example not meet your requirements?

Comment: There is no difference between this model and mine.

Comment: I add the CategoryID after your comment, but this time I get different error, SqlException: Invalid column name 'CategoryName'. Now I am trying to fix that one.

Comment: I display the categoryName instead of categoryID on the IndexPage. I think this cause a problem when I add new product

Comment: This is ok, you can publish the complete code of your view and action in your post, or you can open a new post.

Comment: And where did this exception occur.

Comment: I dont know the rules of stackoverflow exaclty, but can you share your mail addres. Can I send you?

Comment: You can edit [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOvxg.png).

Comment: In your model,`public Guid CategoryID { get; set; } public string CategoryName { get; set; }` is unnecessary,because you can get them by `product.Category.Id/Name`

Comment: Or you can upload to github